# What column data type should I use for storing large amounts of text or html

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a column in a table which used to be varchar(255) in the beginning and due to some design changes now it is varchar(1536) = 1024 + 512. I will not be searching or indexing this field, does it make sense to store this value in a different data type other than a varchar if you would like to optimize this for performance?

Comment: This should solve the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322569/whats-the-best-way-to-store-html-code-in-mysql

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, it will be better if you can store the values in the "`TEXT`" data type. For more details, please read [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html).

Regarding knowledge of storage requirements, you can read [this one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 103):

You should use `TEXT` like the others said, but there is some important advice every time you use TEXT or BLOB: **decouple them form your base table** as they really slow down accessing the table. Imagine the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    title VARCHAR(40),
    author_id INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE article_body (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    body TEXT
);
```

Whenever you list articles you can use the `article` table (last 5 articles of author 33):

```
SELECT id, title FROM article WHERE author_id=33 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5
```

And when someone really opens the article you can use something like:

```
SELECT a.title, ab.body
FROM article AS a
   LEFT JOIN article_body AS ab ON ab.id = a.id
WHERE a.id=82
```

Comment: But if you put the body in the same table as the other data and when accessing just the id and title using the first SELECT query above, does that really slow down the table? I mean you don't read any body text when executing the query.

Comment: @Oskwish For common field types like `INT`, `VARCHAR`, `DATE` etc. the storage engine will reserve the maximum space. For example a VARCHAR(100) will always have 100 bytes (+meta info) in the record. This way a constant **record length** can be calculated and the n-th record will always be at the offset `n * record length`. - In the other hand it would be quite wasteful to reserve 65536 byte for every `TEXT` field so it allocates space dynamically. In this situation a redord's size is no longer fixed and it takes more operations to deal with them.

Comment: @Oskwish Also there are some other tricks. In your example using `id` and `title` : If there is an index containing these fields, MySQL can directly read the data out of the index and not touch the table data at all. - This is helpful in some cases, but won't replace the technique I described.

Comment: I know this is really old, but this example would be really useful together with a snippet of how you insert data so that these two tables indexes matches (I guess that's the only identifier that can be used here to make sure they match when joining them)

Comment: @Strechingmycompetence I believe the tables are inferring the records would be added at the same time, presuming then that the IDs would line up. I will be adding a 3rd column (`article_id`) to the `article_body` table referencing the relevant `article` `id`.

Comment: @KeithDC `article_body.id` is the same as `article.id`. You can implement it according to your db naming practices of course.

Comment: That is true. I typically use an auto-increment on my IDs, so cannot guarantee two records inserted into separate tables having the same ID. But I agree you can certainly set those to static fields, which would ensure they are the same (or some other implementation, as you suggested).

Answer (score 10):

You should be using a file, not a database to store this. Especially not MySQL. I made a writeup once explaining what happens if you for example download images out of a database BLOB, see http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/36-Serving-Images-From-A-Database.html. Using files, you can use the web server fast path using the sendfile(2) system call, and it is much faster to use this.

MySQL also has no BLOB API. That means, it is impossible to upload or download objects larger than max_allowed_packet, and it is hard to work your way around that using SUBSTRING(), because that will make needless copies of strings in server memory.

If you absolutely MUST store BLOB or TEXT data in the server, you have the choice of TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT and LARGETEXT which are limited to 255, 65535, 16 MB and 4GB of data in the server, additionally constrained by max_allowed_packet.

Large BLOB or TEXT information will completely wreck data density in your table. It is useful to create an artificial 1:1 or 1:0 relationship to a BLOB table, and then store the blobs in this extra table.

When MySQL shows a query plan that is 'using tempoary', it means that the server needs to materialize the result set table in the server before delivering the result. This is being done using MEMORY tables, if possible. Any TEXT or BLOB type cannot be represented in MEMORY tables, hence the temporary table then hits the disk as a MyISAM table instead.

You need to scan for such query plans, and convert them into something that loads the ID values of the BLOB/TEXT values instead. In a second query, you'd then SELECT id, thetext FROM texttable WHERE id in ( ... ) to get the TEXT/BLOB values. That will make the query with 'using temporary' not use TEXT or BLOB types, and you can get the TEXT fields then with a trivial query that runs without 'using temporary'.

You can learn more about the internals of MySQL TEXT and BLOB storage by reading http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/

Comment: "Large BLOB or TEXT information will completely wreck data density in your table." Is this true even if you're only using the column to store 2kb of data?

Comment: It depends on the InnoDB format (see mysqlperformanceblog link at the end). But assume you are putting 2KB TEXTs plus say 64 byte of other data into a 16 KB InnoDB page. Leaves you with 5-6 rows/block, as opposed to hundreds otherwise. Very slow if you search on non-blob data. That's the reason BLOB storage changed in later versions of InnoDB (Barracuda ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC), essentially automatically building such an external table internally.

Answer (score 4):

I am here after get stuck in my development.
In my website:
I used `TEXT` datatype in MYSQL to store the content of the `textarea` given by user input. Today I give a large text (112KB) in the textarea to store in DB.
and it breaks.
Then I read from internet -

> ***TINYTEXT**: 255 characters - 255 B*
> ***TEXT**: 65,535 characters - 64 KB*
> ***MEDIUMTEXT**: 16,777,215 - 16 MB*
> ***LONGTEXT**: 4,294,967,295 characters - 4 GB*

For me I have to switch to the **MEDIUMTEXT**.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `text` for columns with variable length.