# Store large content in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Hi I am trying to store large data content in mysql database. For that i set Datatype as TEXT but still it limits to store the data. So what will be the solution for string large content in Mysql tables and retrieve the same.

I am storing news description in one of my mysql table.

Suggest!!! Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text

Comment: TEXT can handle 64k bytes, is that a simple description, or the full text of a long news article?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458376/what-column-data-type-should-i-use-for-storing-large-amounts-of-text-or-html

Comment: @MarkBaker, Yeah that is what i too mentioned. `TEXT` is far enough.

Comment: Define `large`. Answer would heavily depend if that is bytes, kilobytes, megabytes or gigabytes.

Answer (score 2):

See more in : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

```
TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT       L + 1 bytes, where L < 2^8    (255 Bytes)
BLOB, TEXT               L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16   (64 Kilobytes)
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT   L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24   (16 Megabytes)
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT       L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32   (4 Gigabytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TEXT` datatype is far more than enough. Seems like you are not satisfied, so go for [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) (Binary Large Objects)

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR is limited to 255 characters in all mysql versions <= 5.0.3

Various Types of TEXT fields : TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT.

```
TINYTEXT    256 bytes    
TEXT    65,535 bytes    ~64kb
MEDIUMTEXT   16,777,215 bytes   ~16MB
LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes     ~4GB
```

A `BLOB` can be 65535 bytes maximum. `MEDIUMBLOB` for 16777215 bytes or a `LONGBLOB` for 4294967295 bytes.

Difference between `TEXT` & `BLOB` : `BLOB` is used for storing binary data & `TEXT` is used to store large strings.

More Details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Have you ever tried to store anything more than few megabytes? LONGTEXT limit of 4GB is purely theoretical and is not attainable in practice

Comment: @mvp I've Stored Maximum of few MB's But this is what they written in their official documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Typically hard problems start at 16MB and anything over that is so painful as to be completely unusable. Read [this article](http://www.moojuice.net/posts/inserting-large-blobs-in-mysql) as someone tried to insert largest blob possible - they gave up at 200MB.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to change maximum allowed packet size:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet