# How much does decoupling tables in MySQL improve performance?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, database-performance

I am designing the database to store some blog posts in MySQL. I recently ran across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459018/2317532) which advises that when you have:

1. A table that will be queried regularly (e.g. a listing of blog posts), but
2. One column in that table holds a large amount of data that will not be regularly accessed (the blog content)

Then it'd be better for performance if you store that the content in a separate table, so when you generate the listing, it'd be quicker.

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    title VARCHAR(40),
    author_id INT(10) UNIGNED,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE article_text (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    body TEXT
);
```

Does this affect performance even if the column is not part of the query:

```
SELECT id, title FROM article WHERE author_id=33 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5
```

And at what scale does it become a performance issue? (A few hundred, thousands? Millions?)

Comment: Remember `TEXT` is pretty puny by default. You might want `LONGTEXT` to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With MySQL 5.5 and later, the InnoDB storage engine supports the [Barracuda file format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-format.html). In order to use the Barracuda file format for InnoDB, you must use a file-per-table tablespace, or use a generic table space (the single-file "system" InnoDB tablespace does NOT support Barracuda).

Prior to Barracuda (Antelope), [MySQL always stored at least the first 768 bytes of a TEXT column in the clustered (primary key) index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-compression-internals-storage-blobs.html). In that case, having a TEXT column, even when not referencing it, increased the size of each row in the clustered index (leaf nodes). This slowed table scanning on the other non-TEXT columns since less pages fit on each page (more pages to scan on average to find what you're looking for), yet increased performance when scanning the TEXT column (the first 768 bytes anyway). Are you doing a lot of table scanning? Hopefully you're able to use indexes to avoid table scanning.

Indexes are [b-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and key searches are done at the internal nodes, which contain only the key. For the clustered index, that's only the primary key, so clustered index searches are unaffected by the amount of data in the leaf node (but are affected by primary key size).

With the Barracuda file system for InnoDB, the entire TEXT column is stored in overflow pages (which can be compressed). No part of it is stored in the clustered index (leaf nodes). So, if you're using the Barracuda file system, let MySQL do the separation for you and just put the TEXT column in the same table. You're not gaining anything in that case, since MYSQL is already putting the TEXT column somewhere else and isn't affecting scanning the non-TEXT columns.

If you are using Antelope, you might consider splitting it if you are scanning the non-TEXT columns frequently (which you should avoid anyway),  and you rarely referenced the TEXT column. Splitting it into two tables, to read the whole record, you now have to do searches on two clustered indexes, which is twice as expensive as one.

I could also see wanting to split it with Antelope on a system where MySQL had limited RAM for the InnoDB buffer space, and you rarely referenced the TEXT column. The leaf nodes that contained the non-TEXT columns would be more likely to stay in memory if they were smaller.

Comment: Good remarks about the important change in MySQL 5.5.

Comment: I will quibble with one statement -- all indexing is based on BTrees, not binary searches.  A million rows may have 3 levels in its BTree; this depth unlikely to grow/shrink even if the row changes by 768 bytes in size.  I suggest that the search time for a point query is almost identical.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusAdams for you answer, I guess I'll need to research on Barracuda, Antelope, b-trees, leaf nodes, cluster index etc. for me to fully appreciate your answer!

Comment: Wouldn't one get the same benefit with a covering index on the non-TEXT attributes? (Assuming of course that full table scans are infrequent)

Comment: @symcbean, scanning a covering index might be a substitute over splitting the table if memory is of no concern. If you're not using the covering index to satisfy searches, you're using a lot of memory on redundant data, just to scan it. Now, if you're talking about an index avoiding a table scan, yes, I already mentioned that in the answer. Of course, some queries just don't utilize indexes completely (to limit the result set), and some scanning is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all your questions.

"Vertical partitioning" (building a "parallel table") is useful when the `TEXT` (or `BLOB`, etc) is not always needed.

When you do not need the `TEXT`, it performs better because of less bulk in that table.

When you do need the `TEXT`, you are probably fetching only one (or very few) rows, so the `JOIN` into the extra table is not noticeably costly.

I have two databases, each with 200K rows, split like that.  Both have scaled just fine.  I would expect millions, even billions, to be no problem.  (Well, "billions" has lots of problems, but vertical partitioning is one of the solutions.)

Your example `SELECT` needs a 'compound' `INDEX(author_id, created) in order to scale.  But that is independent of the vertical partitioning.

Comment: Unless you're doing `SELECT *` the overhead of a `TEXT` column is generally moderate. Marcus explains.

Comment: The 5.5 comments from @Marcus Adams are valid; I have no direct experience with which to compare.  (My tables were built in 5.1 days.)

Comment: Absolutely. I've built a large-scale schema exactly like this because it dates from that era as well, but now I'd just inline them to avoid the mess that creates. (Actually, I'd use Postgres, but that's another issue.)